# How to prevent reading next line when next() is used in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the lines:

```
for line in f:
    if 'ipsum' in next(f):    #just want to check
        print("Hello")
```

What I want is to only check what is there on the next line, not overall jump to the next line. What I want is something like:

```
for line in f:
    if 'ipsum' in next(f):    #just checking
        print("Hello")
        next(f) #then actually jump to the next line
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: '''
junk.txt is:
one
two
three
...
ten
'''

import sys

filehandle = open("junk.txt", "r")
lines = filehandle.readlines()
currentline = 0

for line in lines:
    if currentline == len(lines) - 1:
        continue
    nextline = currentline + 1
    if "three" in lines[nextline]:
        print (line)
    currentline += 1  #tried to answer this, wrote it up and now can't submit an answer :(  This works.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can not do that this way. I think you will have to use a list to store the lines of your file. You are using an iterator and you can not see what is next without actually calling next()